# Microservice communication over HTTP for Internal Traffic and Pretty Urls

Tags: iis, microservices, url-rewrite-module, arr

I have two microservices and a website that I am hosting all on the same box in IIS like this:

Default Web Site

1. Microservice1 - GET /api/values - Needs JWT token
2. Microservice2 - GET /api/values/1/objects - Needs JWT Token
3. Website

Requirements:

1. Microservice to microservice communication should be done over HTTP.
2. Website to microservice communication should be done over HTTPS.
3. Client (non-Website) to the public API should be rate limited.  But traffic from Website to microservice should not be rate limited.

How can I do this? I know of IIS Rate Limiting, ARR, and URL Rewrites but how do I put all of this together? Is there a typical pattern for this type of behavior in microservices hosted on the same box?

Answer (score 1):

**Pattern**

There is a well-known pattern called [API Gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html), which I would recommend you as a first choice. It is basically a single entry-point to handle all the requests, but it doesn't work just as a reverse proxy, it might also include resources like throttling, rate limit, authentication, and so on.

**Rate Limit**

The clients always access the public domain of your application from an external network, which is the place the rates are monitored. While your services should communicate between themselves by local networks, such as IP address or service name (container name), and there is no control here. And of course, local communication is much faster than external ones.

**SSL**

As you have a central point to handle the requests, you can set the SSL in this instance, and it will listen to HTTPS calls proxying them to the internal services. If they are all in the same server, it's quite easy to configure and make them work together using [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

**Gateway API**

As an API Gateway that I strongly recommend you to look at [Kong](https://konghq.com/). It is easy to use, works really well and it might solve the majority of your issues, even for complex scenarios.

**Complex Scenarios**

Just to give a general overview of complex scenarios and scalability, you would need some [service discovery](https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-in-a-microservices-architecture/), which would centralize the availability and distribution of the requests through the services. For example: when you access abc.example.com, it could redirect the request to three different service instances (10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3). A good tool that handles it is [Consul](https://www.consul.io/discovery.html).